# Change default search engine in chrome on Android to google.co.uk instead of google.com

Tags: google-chrome, android

I am not in the UK but on my Android phone in chrome, I want results from google.co.uk and not google.com - how do I change the search engine. There is no option in the settings (see image).[Search engine settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrNAc.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the existing browser enter google.co.uk and search for it.
You will then be on google.co.uk search page. Do a search but not using the url box (that is still linked to google.com)
The goto chrome/settings/search engine. You will now find google.co.uk is listed. select it (i.e. make default)
Back out of settings, close chrome, restart chrome
You now have google co.uk as your search engine
Took me about an hour searching, but i knew it could be done because i had done it 4 years ago on a previous tablet (probably took me an hour then too)

Comment: Works as of April 22

Comment: Seems like you sometimes have to do "clear browsing data" first to get it to show up.